# Django Count and Group By Two Field's Values

Tags: django, group-by, count, annotations, aggregate

I have a model like this :

```
CLASS_TYPE = ( ("A","A Class"), ("B", "B Class") , ("C", "C Class") , ("D", "D Class") ) 

class Student(models.Model):
   systemId    = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True )
   studentNo   = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True )
   country     = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   clasType    = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_TYPE )
   recordDate = models.DateField() 
...
```

And have a lot of records.

I am interesting with two fields only "**country**" and "**classType**".
I want to count all class types, according to country and sum .

I want to get this `list` of dictionaries from the `Student` model :

> ```
> [
>     { "country":"USA" , "A" : Count_Of_A_Class_in_USA , "B" : Count_Of_B_Class_in_USA , "C" : countCinUSA , "D": count_D_in_USA , "Total" : total_students_in_USA } ,
>     {"Country":"England" , "A" : A_in_England ...., "C":C_in_England... , "Total" : students_in_England }
> ]
> ```

How can i get this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first make a query that, per country and per clasType, obtains the number of `Student`s:

```
qs = Student.objects.values('country', 'clasType').annotate(
    n=Count('pk')
).order_by('country', 'clasType')
```

Now we can use [**`itertools.groupby`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group these dictionaries together in dictionaries that are more compact:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [
    {'country': c, ** { li['clasType']: li['n'] for li in l } }
    for c, l in groupby(qs, itemgetter('country'))
]
```

But we still need to do "patching": it is possible that a country has not all `clasType`s, we probably want to add `0`s for these, and furthermore we need to calculate the total. We can do that with:

```
for subd in data:
    total = 0
    for ct, _ in CLASS_TYPE:
        total += subd.setdefault(ct, 0)
    subd['Total'] = total
```

Now `data` contains a list of dictionaries, with every dictionary a `'country'` and `'Total'` key, and per `CLASS_TYPE` a key and the number of `Student`s for that `CLASS_TYPE`.

Comment: Thank you really but , getting this error  : 

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<console>", line 3, in <module>
File "<console>", line 3, in <listcomp>
TypeError: 'itertools._grouper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @mevaka: yes, I made a small mistake, now it should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you a lot again.
But again an error :) , Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'stdefault'

Comment: @mevaka: and that was a typo :), it is `setdefault`.